# Links break when when URL includes angle brackets

Tags: support, markdown-rendering

A link in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048100/how-do-i-test-to-see-that-a-directory-is-empty-in-ant/3048134#3048134) did not format properly.  I'm guess that's because there are `<` and `>` in the URL?

This text:

```
You can use the `pathconvert` element to do that, see [this example](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-user/200512.mbox/<4397C619.5010106@gmx.de>).
```

gets formatted like this:

You can use the `pathconvert` element to do that, see [this example](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-user/200512.mbox/<4397C619.5010106@gmx.de>).

Answer (score 3):

Workaround: replace the brackets with `%3C` and `%3E`.

```
You can use the `pathconvert` element to do that, see [this example](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-user/200512.mbox/%3C4397C619.5010106@gmx.de%3E).
```

You can use the `pathconvert` element to do that, see [this example](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-user/200512.mbox/%3C4397C619.5010106@gmx.de%3E).